# C++ class layout for memory mapped io

Tags: c++, layout, memory-mapping

I want to use a mmio device in a C++ environment. Is there a way for me to create a class that represents the layout of the devices registers, such that reading and writing to the fields will read and write to the registers?

Say that the offset `0x0` contains reg0 and `0x04` contains reg1. Could I create class:

```cpp
class MyDevice {
    public:
        int reg0;
        int reg1;

};
```

such that accessing `reg0` or `reg1` would act as register accesses?

Comment: Probably.  You needs a lot more details if you are looking for a more detailed answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike Links to resources would probably be enough for my use case, but I will add some details

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. I have added some more context. Does that help?

Comment: Yes. Check your C++ compiler's documentation. Most C++ compilers have custom directives or attributes that can be used to force, disable, or enforce padding of structure fields, which can be used for things of this nature, creating structures with specific layouts.

Comment: You might find this interesting [Handling a family of Hardware Devices with a single implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM83l5NZ15c)

Comment: Are you trying to mimic the register layout in a class, or are you trying to create class members that actually map to the underlying register addresses?  If the latter, you can cast the mapped addresses to pointers of the correct type and then have your data members be references to those dereferenced pointers.

Comment: I want to mimic the register layout in a class @user1806566